# Hyperbolic geometry models

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

Hyperbolic geometry models

The Hyperboloid model and Poincare disk model are equivalent and I am looking for geometric proof of this fact (or geometric intuition behind it?).
In [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-42101-4), the proof of Theorem 5.32,  it is showed by explicitly chasing how the metric changes under the transformation between those models.

Is there more geometric proof  of it? Any references?

Comment: Short answer: they have same constant sectional curvature, complete and simply connected, so isometric.

Comment: Hyperbolic geometry is categorical, i.e. any two models (of the same dimension) are isomorphic.